# How to solve ACPI error Emergency mode loop?

Tags: 18.04

When I boot my computer I am presented with the following errors:

[image: Error List]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: From the looks of the error, you have either a missing partition or almost dead hard drive 

Comment: Most likely the latter.

Comment: I can see hard disk data in ubuntu live USB after mounting from Disks .but cannot transfer all files .Getting message you are not owner. So cannot reinstall till I transfer data.

Comment: Solved after following steps.                           1 Boot computer with Live USB
2 Open Terminal
3 Run sudo e2fsck -cfpv /dev/sda1
4 Sudo -i
5 Fsck -y /dev/sda1
6 Exit
7 Reboot system remove USB and wait
8 When system start Umount /dev/sda6
9 Fsck -y /dev/sda6
10 Reboot